# Bend feature of simple deform modifier doesn't work as intended

Tags: modifiers, objects

I was trying to use the bend feature of the simple deform modifier, but was unable to made it work as intended (i.e it doesn't bend the edges following a round shape, instead it bends both ends to each other). Here's the preview of the issue.

https://imgur.com/a/whQszjj

Do any of you guys know what is the issue here? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like you have unapplied rotations. Can you try hitting Ctrl+A followed by R, and see if that resolves the problem?

Answer (score 4):

It should work:

[image]

Maybe your mesh is not subdivided the right way.

Other possibilities: the object is scaled or rotated in object mode.